# disable control+ 1 to switch to Desktop 1 on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos

I didn't have this problem until the Mac updated to macOS Monterey. Control+1 is a shortcut in a lot of jet brain tools like IntelliJ, phpStorm, etc. however, it's switching to Desktop 1 when I press Control+1 now. Any idea how to disable that?

Comment: Keyboard prefs, shortcuts. Can provide a proper answer when I get back to my desktop

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you very much. That's exactly where it is, Keyboard shortcuts/Mission Control. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Monterey to be able to provide the correct picture, but this hasn't moved in many years, so the location is the same

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control

[image]